# How to retrieve correct Rails singleton instance from Resque workers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading, singleton, resque

I have a singleton store in my Rails application which holds some assets. It's accessible like this :

`Synchronizer.instance`

For some reasons I don't have any database service in my project apart from a Redis instance where Resque does its magic.

I would like to access the assets from the Resque workers like this :

`Synchronizer.instance.asset(id)`

Because workers are in different threads, the instance of Synchronizer I retrieve is not the same as the Rails environment's.

`Rails:
Synchronizer:0x007feb5c389a10
Resque:
Synchronizer:0x00000008566f00`

It kinds of kill the interest of using a Singleton in the first place. I could pass information about asset as a Hash into workers instead, but is there another way to access the proper singleton instance?

Comment: You can't access an object from another process. Storing the asset information in Redis would be an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Stefan commented, it is not possible to access a ruby object from another process, and using a singleton to hold assets was a bad idea anyway. I learnt that you should **always avoid singletons** when you can. I finally cached the assets in Redis and retrieve them when needed.